# Deploy and automatically compile servlet with tomcat7

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I'm having trouble getting a simple Java servlet to run under tomcat7 (fresh install from ubuntu repository).

It is a single .java file with `@WebServlet("/TestServlet")`. I put it into `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/TestServlet/WEB-INF` and would like Tomcat to recognize and automatically compile it (also, when I change the source file). How do I set this up in a simple way?

Comment: Also check out this popular tutorial: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile your code using java compiler (or IDE). Then deploy `*.class` file(s) under servlet container (Tomcat in your case).

The class file must be under your `WEB-INF/classes` directory. If you class belongs to package like `com.myservlet` and its name is `HellowServlet` put it into file `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/TestServlet/WEB-INF/com/myservlet/HelloServlet.class`

EDIT:

if you indeed want make tomcat to *compile* your servlet, write JSP. This is a key feature of JSP: it can be deployed as a source code and is compiled automatically to servlet by container.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse IDE and click  "Add Server" to add TomCat server. It will work directly